# Variable not getting updated in apply

Tags: perl

Quoting from Perldoc for apply in List::AllUtils

> Applies BLOCK to each item in LIST and returns a list of the values after BLOCK has been applied. In scalar context, the last element is returned.  This function is similar to "map" but will not modify the elements of the input list.

I want to check whether the number is an Armstrong number or not. Since map in scalar context returns the number of elements and apply returns the last element which is final `$sum`. I used the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use List::AllUtils qw(apply sum);
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

say "Enter the input : ";
my $input_number = <STDIN>;
chomp($input_number);
my $sum;
my $out = apply { $sum += $_ ** 3 } split //, $input_number ;
say $out;
```

I expect `$sum` to be returned to `$out`. But I get the last character of `$input_number`.

Output :

```
Enter the input : 
153
3
```

Edit :

I have the solution for Armstrong number. I need to know why the `apply` doesn't return `$sum` and returned the last character of `$input_number`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need apply or map, just a for loop:

```
my $input_number = 153;
my $sum = 0;
$sum += $_ ** 3 for split //, $input_number ;

print ($sum == $input_number) ? "Yep, it's an armstrong num\n" : "nope\n";
```

If you wanted to pull the last element, you could do that like the following:

```
my $out = (map {$sum += $_ ** 3} split //, $input_number)[-1];
```

To show what `apply` is actually does, one can just look at the source:

```
sub apply (&@) {
    my $action = shift;
    &$action foreach my @values = @_;
    wantarray ? @values : $values[-1];
}
```

This makes a copy of the original array, and then runs the code block on each element.  Note though, that you must actually change the value of `$_` or apply will simply return the original element.

I believe apply was intended specifically for the case of applying a regular expression to an array without being destructive to the original array.  For example, the following are equivalent:

```
my @newarray = apply {s/\n//g} @oldarray;
my @newarray = map {my $text = $_; $text =~ s/\n//g; $text} @oldarray;
```

So ultimately, the only way to get apply to work in the way you expect with your code is to do the following:

```
my $out = apply { $_ = $sum += $_ ** 3 } split //, $input_number ;
```

Comment: I have the solution but doesn't the apply block needs to return the $sum ?

Comment: No apply at scalar context doesn't return the size. Check it with input number as 157. It will return 7 instead of 3.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I could use index on map list. But I am still vague on apply.

Comment: Added more info on what apply is actually doing

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AllUtils#apply-BLOCK-LIST):

> **apply BLOCK LIST**
>
> Applies BLOCK to each item in LIST and returns a list of the values after BLOCK has been applied. **In scalar context, the last element is returned.**

To spell out the documentation a little more clearly: `apply` takes a list, applies `BLOCK` to it, and then returns either

- the (possibly modified) list *(list context)*
- the last element of the (possibly modified) list *(scalar context)*

You haven't actually modified the list, you've only changed the `$sum` variable, so the result you get is the last element of the list you passed in.

Use the `reduce` function instead:

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);

my $sum = reduce { $a + ($b ** 3) } 1 .. 10;
# 3025
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return $sum last value? . It returns $_ values only.

Comment: It returns the values in `LIST` after applying `BLOCK`. You never change the items in `LIST` (i.e. `$_`), so you will always get the last item of your original list.

Comment: So it builds up a list of modified `$_` and not like `map` ? . I guess you could add the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what the documentation means by "list of the values after BLOCK has been applied".  It returns the value of `$_` after each application of BLOCK, not the return value of the BLOCK itself.  Unlike `map`, `$_` is initialized to a copy of the element.

Comment: I got more misunderstood by the statement in Perldoc that says that this function is similar to map. Thanks @cjm